# what problem about sprintf_s function error

Tags: c

```
char* pszBuffer = NULL, * pszNewBuffer = NULL;

    pszBuffer = (char*)malloc(24);
    **sprintf_s(pszBuffer, sizeof(pszBuffer), "%s", "TestString");**

    printf("[%p] %u %s\n",
        pszBuffer, _msize(pszBuffer), pszBuffer);
```

In this code, "buffer is too small".
what problem is this?

When I changed from "sizeof(pszBuffer)" to "24(just number size)", it can run.
so I think, sprintf_S function can not use sizeof.
Am I right?

Comment: `sizeof(pszBuffer)` is the size of the pointer, not the amount of memory it points to. Usually 4 or 8 depending on platform. If instead you didn't use dynamic allocation and had something like `char buffer[24];` then `sizeof(buffer)` would be 24.

Comment: `sizeof(pszBuffer)` is the size of the pointer. Not the size of allocated memory

Comment: add `printf("%d", sizeof(pszBuffer));` and see what you get

Comment: @pm100 `%d` for `sizeof()`?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Since the array referenced by `pszBuffer` is allocated via `malloc()` at runtime, the compiler can't know its size.

Here, `sizeof(pszBuffer)` is the size of the pointer variable itself, which is most likely 4 bytes or 8 bytes, hence the "buffer is too small" error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You're right. I've deleted the sentence.